# String input from the user

Tags: c, input

I'm making a Command-Line Operating system (command line interpreter). How to I get a line of input from the user?

Comment: Whad did you try so far ?

Comment: A command line interpreter is a program like any other, not directly part of the OS. As you desgined/wrote your OS, only you know how to get user-input.

Comment: I tried to use BASH and POSIX, but I can't figure how to use them to make OS, so i tried to make the command line myself. I don't know how to get a line of user input, but I know how to do the rest.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what an operating system is.  You cannot make and OS from bash and POSIX.  POSIX is an API for an existing operating system, and bash is a command shell for an existing POSIX operating system.  If your program requires an operating system to run; it is definitively not itself an _operating system_.  An application that accepts user commands and executes them, is not itself an operating system either.

Comment: If your program is launched from the bootloader, manages application access to the hardware, manages system memory, allows the launching and scheduling of user programs then it is probably an operating system.  It may even have a command shell.  It seems that what you are asking about is simply an alternative command shell.  Really if you have to ask this question you are not in a position for the complexities of an operating system.

Comment: It seems that your question might simply be about getting a line of user input.  There is no need to tell anyone why you want to do that, even if what you are calling an OS is not an an OS.  As such _one_ answer is to use the standard `fgets()` function.

Comment: Study the source code of *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shells, such as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). If you want to make an OS from scratch, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) then http://osdev.org/

Answer (score 2):

> I'm making a Command-Line Operating system. How to I get a line of input form a user?

The first things you'll need are some boot code (to get things like a memory map from firmware), physical memory management, virtual memory management, a scheduler and some kind of inter-process communication (IPC).

The next things you'll need is some kind of device enumeration framework, to help make a tree of devices to keep track of everything; followed by scanning PCI buses to add them to the tree of devices.

Next you'll want to tackle device resources - determining IO port ranges, memory mapped IO ranges and managing IRQs. This can be messy (e.g. AML interpreter for ACPI to determine IO APIC inputs, and "interrupt vector allocator" to handle MSI).

The next thing is USB controller drivers, USB hub driver and maybe (for obsolete  hardware) a PS/2 controller driver. These all find devices connected to them (e.g. USB keyboard) and add them to the tree of devices, and then communicate with the drivers for those devices. At some point you might also want to worry about fault tolerance, power management and hot-plug (e.g. if a USB controller driver crashes, is put to sleep or is removed/unplugged; then you'd use the "tree of devices" to figure out which other drivers are effected).

Next, you'll want keyboard drivers. Specifically, a driver for "USB HID" (which is a single specification that covers all human input devices - keyboard, mouse, touchpad, joystick, ..), and maybe (for obsolete  hardware) a PS/2 keyboard driver. Note that you'll probably also want an on-screen keyboard for touch-screen users, and input method editor/s to assist with input of some languages (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc).

Next, you'll want something for video output. Typically early boot code uses minimal "just enough to display boot log" code (if it's not hidden by a pretty splash image); but you'll want something that's actually good instead (likely including a font engine with Unicode support).

The end result of all of the above is that you'll have a set of (hopefully "standardised for your OS" and documented) device driver interfaces and all of the things that device drivers depend on; a way (the inter-process communication I mentioned near the start) to send "events" (key-presses) to a process and a way for processes to display output (draw things on the screen).

Once all that is done you can write a terminal emulation layer. This is a thing (process?) that hides all the nice modern stuff (e.g. OpenGL, events) under a layer of historic memorabilia (so that the end user's computer, which is likely to be capable of emulating realistic virtual reality environments, can be used as a glorified teleprinter from early last century). This also uses the inter-process communication I mentioned near the start (e.g. maybe pipes - stdin, stdout) to communicate with a child process.

Finally, you can begin writing some sort of command shell. This is just a process that communicates with its parent (e.g. with the terminal emulation layer) via. whatever you're using for inter-process communication (e.g. stdin, stdout) that allows users to start other processes and handles a little "forwarding" (e.g. while a child process is running, keyboard input that shell receives from terminal emulation layer gets forwarded by shell to its child process, and output the shell receives from its child gets forwarded by shell back to shell's parent/terminal emulator).

Note that as part of writing the command shell, or before writing the command shell, you might want to write some libraries to handle simple chores (e.g. getting a whole line of user input and handling things like "home", "end", "delete", "backspace", etc) so that these libraries can be used by all programs including the command shell itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems doubtful that you are truly implementing an *operating system*, but if you simply mean a *command shell*, then it might follow the following structure:

```
int main()
{
    char command_line[1024] ;
    char* input = NULL ;
    int errorlevel = 0 ;

    do
    {
        // Show command prompt
        putchar( '>' ) ;
        fflush( stdout ) ;

        // Get command line
        input = fgets( command_line, stdin, sizeof(command_line) ) ;
        if( input != NULL )
        {
            // Process command line
            errorlevel = parseCommand( input, &errorlevel ) ;
        }

    } while( input != NULL ) ;

    return errorlevel ;
}
```

where parse `parseCommand()` is a function with the following interface:

```
int parseCommand( const char* cmd_line, const int* current_errorlevel ) ;
```

Here the answer to your question of how to get a line of user input is the `fgets()` function.

The complex part perhaps is in the implementation of `parseCommand()`; user input is the easy part, but make a start - have fun.

Comment: Hi, i've tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: @user10693192 : You need to consider the comments on your question and _improve_ the question.  "didn't work" is not going to get us any where - you need to provide more feedback than that!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike everyone I appreciate you thinking big but focus on the basics first as it is good to start small. Also, what you are doing is making a command line interpreter and not an OS. There's a big difference between the two. For an OS, you need a kernel, GUI, etc. However here's the solution to your query:

You can use gets, but you might receive a warning in this one

```
char *gets(char *str)
```

To overcome above limitation, we can use fgets as :

```
char *fgets(char *str, int size, FILE *stream)
```

Using %[^\n]%*c inside scanf

```
scanf(“%[^\n]%*c”, str);
```

This one comes quite in handy when using for loop.

You have a bright future if you think innovatively (people lack this). 
But it's always better to brush your base before going big. Welcome to stackoverflow :)